# Merge "knowledge-base" and "knowledge-organization"?

Tags: discussion, tag-merge

I think the difference is quite subtle (one being the storage itself, the other the process to put something into it or take it away) – but does that really justify separate tags? I'd say we should merge [knowledge-organization](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge-organization) (× 14) with [knowledge-base](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge-base) (× 10), optionally making one a synonym to the other (to prevent it from unwanted re-appearing).

Please bring up reasons why the two might be really distinct; in that case I'd withdraw my request and alter it to "creating the corresponding tag-wikis to make that difference clear" :)

Comment: 6 out of the total 18 questions tagged with either have both tags, seems like a good thing to consolidate.

Comment: @Undo that's how I came to this (the newest one of those double-tagged) :)

Comment: @Undo May I "ping" this – now that 10 days have passed, and only positive feedback was given? As Pacerier suggested, we could go with `knowledge-management`. Not sure about the synonyms, though.

Comment: Yep, I'll take a look at this when I get a chance. I'm out in the middle of nowhere with spotty access right now, so not sure when that'll be.

Answer (score 4):

The old term was [Content Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems).

These days, the terms "[Knowledge Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_management)" and "[Knowledge Organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_organization)" are also used. "Knowledge management" will include "[Personal Knowledge Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_knowledge_management)", "Enterprise Knowledge Management", and "Legal Knowledge Management".

Or perhaps the more generic "[Information Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_management)" or "Information Organization" or "[Information Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_architecture)".

Or even more generic, "Information Systems".

("Information" actually has two meanings. It can be used as a [synonym for "knowledge"](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/information), yet in some technical discussions, its used as a synonym for "data", eg in the term "[information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory)".)

Alternatively, there're also lesser-used terms like "Digital Library" and "[Institutional Repository](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_repository)".

Comment: That has a point, definitely. I'm fine with `knowledge-management`. If we'd go for `information-management`, we should definitely keep the `knowledge-*` tags as synonyms to guide people to it.

Comment: I'd second the tag knowledge-management but we should keep the existing ones as synonyms to it or they will reappear.

Comment: "Information Systems" is too generic. Any Database ever is a "Information System". I think "knowledge-management" is the key element here, because the systems we are talking about handle the individual knowledge of people. Thus we should stick to "knowledge-management"

Comment: do you know a community (in the SE network or not) about these topics?